# Flutter | Dart Is there a more elegant way to write this code?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  var showTextA = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: (showTextA)
          ? [
              Text("A"),
              Text("B"),
              Text("C"),
            ]
          : [
              Text("B"),
              Text("C"),
            ],
    );
  }
```

2. or

```
  var havePadding = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (havePadding) ?
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child:...,
    ) : Container(
      child:...,
    );
  }
```

Through the above code, I wonder if you can understand what I mean?
I remember that Dart provided Flutter with some kind of grammatical sugar, but I forgot, I've been looking for it, but I don't know how to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

On based on the code given its better to do like this. Its better to minimize widgets rebuild. If there are only few state widget to changed just managed that one.

```
  var showTextA = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        (showTextA) ? Text("A") : SizedBox(),
        Text("B"),
        Text("C"),
      ],
    );
  }
```

```
  var havePadding = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(havePadding ? 10.0:  0 ),
      child: ....,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to look great:

```dart
List<Widget> getTexts(bool showTextA) {
    if (showTextA) {
        return [Text("A"), Text("B"), Text("C")];
    }
        else {
            return [Text("B"), Text("C")];
        }
}
```

then in `build` method:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        children: getTexts(showTextA)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var showTextA = true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children:[
            if (showTextA) Text("A"),
            Text("B"),
            Text("C"),
          ],
  );
}
```

or

```
var havePadding = true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
      padding: havePadding ? EdgeInsets.all(10.0) : null,
      child: Text('sdfsdf'),
    );
}
```

Comment: For the first example, your answer is the answer I was looking for.For the second example, I think there should be a better way to write it;If you use "?: ", then every time I need to know what the default value of the parameter is!And sometimes some parameter values are not allowed to be NULL.If there is no better solution, I think Google should provide better syntax, or provide a way to easily get the default values for optional parameters.

Comment: yeah, i get that, there should be a better syntax for that. we might be missing something though. however with null safety almost all parameters are null-able. still a waste.

Answer (score 0):

For the first example, since you only have 1 widget inside your condition, it's cleaner to simply replace `? :` for a bracket-free `if`

```
  var showTextA = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
              if(showTextA) Text("A"),
              Text("B"),
              Text("C"),
            ]
    );
  }
```

as for your second example, you could do

```
  var havePadding = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: havePadding ? EdgeInsets.all(10.0) : null //or EdgeInsets.zero,
      child:...,
    )
  }
```

That'll definitely reduce a few lines of code and make it more readable.